# bl.ocks d3 visualization got cut off by the visualization box

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This is my first question ever so please bear with me if the format isn't exactly correct.

I am posting d3.js visualization code to Gists and viewing them from bl.ocks.org. I noticed that my svg canvas is too big (600*600) so the bottom 100 or so got cut off. Of course when I view it in a new tab it is fine.

However, Mike does not seem to have a problem with oversize visualizations, see http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/45943c4af772e38b4f4e.

What is the trick to expand the visualization box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's this line:

```
d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");
```